# wickrme suddenly not opening; core dump; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: snap

Suddenly wickrme does not open on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Anyone know what the heck is going on? I have reinstalled snapd and purged and reinstalled and restarted etc., and I get this same blanking error:

```
~$ wickrme
(WickrMe:3022): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:04:18.457: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1566:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
(WickrMe:3022): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:04:18.461: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3616:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
(WickrMe:3022): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:04:18.462: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4078:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
Gtk-Message: 18:04:18.518: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 18:04:18.519: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[0321/180419.577225:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /opt/qt512/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /opt/qt512. Trying application directory...
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /opt/qt512/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /snap/wickrme/484/usr/bin/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/home/homie/snap/wickrme/484/.QtWebEngineProcess'
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /opt/qt512/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /opt/qt512. Trying application directory...
[0321/180419.697693:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

one option I didn't explore was to install an older version:
it seems that we could install:

latest/stable   5.74.8  18 March 2021
latest/candidate    5.59.11     23 July 2020
latest/beta     5.47.25     11 February 2020

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the 'candidate' version, it works -
It is really an issue with their current so-called 'stable' version...